# org.jboss.msc.service.fail (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jboss, wildfly

**I am trying to run a small web application on WildFly Full 10.1.0, but I am getting following error which I am not able to sort out:**

```
12:12:53,025 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
12:12:53,235 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
12:12:53,311 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
12:12:54,532 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment MySpringHibernate.war
12:12:54,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found MySpringHibernate.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called MySpringHibernate.war.dodeploy
12:12:54,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
12:12:54,624 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
12:12:54,639 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
12:12:54,718 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
12:12:54,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
12:12:54,758 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
12:12:54,804 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
12:12:54,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
12:12:54,807 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
12:12:54,809 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
12:12:54,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
12:12:54,846 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
12:12:54,973 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
12:12:55,027 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
12:12:55,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
12:12:55,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgres
12:12:55,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
12:12:55,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
12:12:55,143 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/home/naveen/JBoss/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
12:12:55,164 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
12:12:55,189 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
12:12:55,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
12:12:55,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
12:12:55,404 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
12:12:55,663 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/test]
12:12:55,767 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/naveen/JBoss/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
12:12:55,774 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/naveen/JBoss/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
12:12:55,792 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "MySpringHibernate.war" (runtime-name: "MySpringHibernate.war")
12:12:56,009 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
12:12:56,042 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:12:56,043 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:12:56,051 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:12:56,052 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:12:56,071 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:12:56,072 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
12:12:56,105 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
12:12:56,202 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
12:12:56,465 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
12:12:56,576 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.MySpringHibernate.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1079)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:284)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.MySpringHibernate.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:723)
    ... 6 more

12:12:56,956 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MySpringHibernate.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.MySpringHibernate.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.MySpringHibernate.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
12:12:56,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "MySpringHibernate.war" (runtime-name : "MySpringHibernate.war")
12:12:56,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.MySpringHibernate.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

12:12:57,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
12:12:57,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:12:57,092 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 4541ms - Started 393 of 647 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
12:12:57,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment MySpringHibernate.war (runtime-name: MySpringHibernate.war) in 13ms
12:12:57,175 WARN  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0357: Notification of type deployment-undeployed is not described for the resource at the address []
12:12:57,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "MySpringHibernate.war" (runtime-name: "MySpringHibernate.war")
12:12:57,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."MySpringHibernate.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./MySpringHibernate.UndertowDeploymentInfoService

12:13:02,011 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDS0004: Found MySpringHibernate.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called MySpringHibernate.war.dodeploy
```

**My pom.xml file is:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sugandh.tdh</groupId>
  <artifactId>MySpringHibernate</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MySpringHibernate Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
  <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
  <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
  <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
  <context.path>SpringRestCrud</context.path>
 </properties>
     <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
          <plugins>
               <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                 <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                 <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
               </plugin>
          </plugins>
     </build>

     <dependencies>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           <version>${log4j.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>jstl</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
           <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>5.1.6</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
           <version>1.9.10</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
          </dependency>
     </dependencies>
</project>
```

**My spring configuration file is**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.sugandh.controller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <!-- bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/Testing" />
  <property name="username" value="postgres" />
  <property name="password" value="hlinaknk" />
 </bean-->

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiName"><value>java:jboss/datasources/Testing</value></property>
</bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.sugandh.model.Employee</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="txManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
  class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

 <bean id="dataDao" class="com.sugandh.dao.DataDaoImpl"></bean>
 <bean id="dataServices" class="com.sugandh.services.DataServicesImpl"></bean>
</beans>
```

my web.xml is:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">

 <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**I am just a beginner in spring-hibernate. 
Can someone please help out in what is going wrong here?**

Comment: You need to declare the DispatcherServlet  either in web.xml or java configuration class.

Comment: I dont see a Maven war plugin in your POM. How you are building the war file.

Comment: <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> is included in POM

Comment: maven compiler plugin and maven war plugin are different. Please have a war plugin included and then check.